# Number of double tangents to an algebraic curve of degree d

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, plane-curves

Let $C$ be a plane real algebraic curve of degree $d$, i.e.,
the zero-set of a two-variable polynomial of degree $d$.

> ***Q1***. Is it the case that the number of double tangents is $O(d^2)$?

I believe this follows from the [Plücker formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_formula). In fact, $d (d-1)$ is
a tight upper bound. Am I reading this correctly? 
(My knowledge of algebraic geometry is thin.)

> ***Q2***. My actual situation is that my curve $C$ is (a) connected, and
>   (b) embedded, that is, it is non-self-intersecting. Is there a smaller
>   upper bound on the number of double tangents with these constraints?

If not, I would be interested in an example that achieves $\Omega(d^2)$ double
tangents.

Comment: The number of bitangents to a plane curve of degree $d$ are $\frac12 d^4-d^3-\frac92 d^2+9d$, which as a special case gives the famous 28 bitangents of a quartic.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Thanks! Can you tell  me where I might find that result? I need to cite it.

Comment: [The schubert manual](https://github.com/jmokland/schubert/blob/master/schubertlib/schubert/src/schubertmanual) is where I have it from.

Comment: With Jan-Magnus's hint, I found "Schubert Calculus according to Schubert," Felice Ronga, [PDF download](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/ronga/preprints/eschubert.pdf).

Comment: Yes it's in [Hermann Schubert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schubert)'s _Kalkül_ _der_ _abzählenden_ _Geometrie_ published in 1879.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of bitangents to a plane curve (from the documentation of the maple package [schubert](http://folk.uib.no/nmajo/schubert/)).

```
proj(2,h,all):             # the dual projective plane
proj(2,j,all):             # the projective plane
bundlesection(C,o(d*j)):   # define a plane curve of degree d
morphism(f,C,Ph,[(d-1)*j]):# the Gauss map to the dual plane
multiplepoint(f,2)/2:      # double points are bitangents or flexes
                           # correct for flexes.  Flexes can of 
                           # course be calculated automatically.
bitangents:=expand(integral(C,%)-(3*d*(d-2)));
                                   4    3        2
                bitangents := 1/2 d  - d  - 9/2 d  + 9 d

subs(d=4,%);
                                   28
```